How to automatically switch between build-in and usb wifi card?
So I run Ubuntu 24.04 LTS. I want have a build-in and a USB wifi card. I want so that when the USB card is plugged in, my laptop automatically switched to it, and when it is plugged out, it should switch back to the built-in card. Any way to do that?
I did find similar questions but none of them had an answer((
All help appreciated!
Here are all the network-card information (nmcli -t):
wlan0: connected to WIFI228_2.4G
    "wlan0"
    wifi (rtl8723bs), A0:2C:36:CB:D3:7D, hw, mtu 1500
    ip4 default
    inet4 192.168.1.129/24
    route4 192.168.1.0/24 metric 600
    route4 default via 192.168.1.1 metric 600
    inet6 fe80::c49b:23f2:e44a:6ebb/64
    route6 fe80::/64 metric 1024

lo: connected (externally) to lo
    "lo"
    loopback (unknown), 00:00:00:00:00:00, sw, mtu 65536
    inet4 127.0.0.1/8
    inet6 ::1/128

wlx347de44fb859: disconnected
    "Realtek Wi-Fi"
    wifi (rtw_8821cu), 34:7D:E4:4F:B8:59, hw, mtu 1500

wlan0 is the built-in card, and the last one is the USB one.

Can you find out the device names off the two WiFi cards and add them to your question? You can run the command nmcli -t -f NAME c show and copy and paste the output from the terminal directly to your question above. Then format the pasted output as code using the {_} icon above the edit window.

I've written a bash script to help with this: https://github.com/waltinator/net-o-matic It watches the connection, and when the connection drops, does a user-specified thing to try to reconnect or do something else.

@waltinator  how do I acctually use your script? Any docs? Where do I put my info in? How does the config even work?

@matveygal Read the net-o-matic script, and the example .conf file. You place the commands to reconnect the Wi-Fi in the .conf file. net-o-matic waits until the network is "Disconnected", then executes the next command from net-o-matic.conf . If you point to a script, you can do anything to reconnect.
